# how to merge multiple dump command result in single file in mysql of same database

Tags: mysql

I have a large database. I need to dump all database in single file with ignoring data of specific tables. My R&D is successful in windows but failure in Linux server.

My db dump commands for windows env is below,

```
F:\xampp\mysql\bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password= db_name --add-drop-table --ignore-table=db_name.table1 > F:\xampp\htdocs\c4s\temp\backup\db_name.sql && F:\xampp\mysql\bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password= --add-drop-table --no-data db_name table2 >> F:\xampp\htdocs\projectName\temp\backup\db_name.sql
```

This works fine!!! But when I execute it in Linux environment second dump option not work..

The dump command for Linux environment is,

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password=mypass db_name db_name.table1 > /var/www/html/projectName/temp/backup/2/db_name.sql && /usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password=mypass --add-drop-table --no-data db_name table2 >> /var/www/html/projectName/temp/backup/db_name.sql
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "second dump option does not work"? You get an error message?

Comment: First dump option >>    
 /usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password=mypass db_name db_name.table1 > /var/www/html/projectName/temp/backup/2/db_name.sql ;                                                                                        Second Dump option >> 
&& /usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password=mypass --add-drop-table --no-data db_name table2 >> /var/www/html/projectName/temp/backup/db_name.sql

Comment: Yes, but this is no new information. What do you mean by "the second dump does not work"? Do you get an error? Is the dump information missing from the file? Is the first dump missing? *What* does not work or *how do you know* that it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

If each dump works individually, just create a small shell script `dump.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password=mypass db_name db_name.table1
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root --password=mypass --add-drop-table --no-data db_name table2
```

You then can dump the result into a file:

```
./dump.sh > /var/www/html/projectName/temp/backup/db_name.sql
```

As you failed to mention what the problem with the original approach is, here a wild guess:

```
> /var/www/html/projectName/temp/backup/2/db_name.sql
>> /var/www/html/projectName/temp/backup/db_name.sql
```

You are dumping in two different files. If you want to dump into the same file, you actually need to name the same file a second time again.

Furthermore, it is not a good idea to pass the password via command line. Anyone on the server can see the password by using `ps` while the backup is running. The best is if you create an option file with the password and all other options you want to use and then make `mysqldump` use this one.

Option file `mysqldump.cnf`:

```
[mysqldump]
password=secret
```

To use the file, pass it via command line, but do *not* give a password at the command line - it will be used from the option file:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=mysqldump.cnf -h localhost -u root …
```

For more information about `mysqldump`, you are free to consult the [mysqldump manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue. ***--no-data*** option don't work if any table of that list(table list after --no-data option) is not found in database.